# Unknown file with .html extension in custom php website hosted on Dreamhost

Tags: php, html, dreamhost

I am working on updating an old php website hosted on Dreamhost and there is a random, unknown file in the project with a `.html` extension: `ajcyss2bv1f18lmrh84tcwhdxx0b8r.html`.

The only thing the file contains is `ajcyss2bv1f18lmrh84tcwhdxx0b8r`.

The original creator of the site did not know where the file came from, or could not remember.

I did multiple searches on Google to seek a better understanding of what this file could be, but could not find a satisfactory answer. This is why I turned to the StackOverflow community.

Does anyone know what this file is? Thank you.

Comment: Might be useful to look inside it a see what its for

Comment: Well I would ignore it, its obviously doing nothing useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is used to prove ownership of the website or domain for software such as Google Search Console or other services. They would be asking you to create this file at your web root when setting up.